# Why am I getting an e-mail saying The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key when I already do ?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

Hi tried to upload my app to Itunes connect , everything was successful (archive etc) but then it didn't appear on iTunes connect, I later got an e-mail saying

"This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data."

However I do have in the info.plist this : Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Where could this come from ? thanks !

Comment: Camera and Photo Library usage are different things and require separate usage descriptions in the plist.

Comment: @dan Hmmm I feel a bit stupid now , haven't been sleeping much lately, anyway, you solved my issue, thanks !